# Icon not showing Android

Tags: android, icons

I have defined the following ApplicationManifest file the problem is that i have created a custom icon but it's not shown i still get the ugly green icon

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.display.helper"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="0.1.124">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.TELEPHONY"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
    <application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name">
      <activity android:name=".GpsTrackActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity> 
       <service android:name=".dhaService" >
       <intent-filter>
       <action
       android:name = "com.display.helper.dhaService">
       </action>
       </intent-filter>
       </service>
       <receiver android:name=".dha">
       <intent-filter>
       <action
       android:name ="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED">
       </action>
       </intent-filter>
       </receiver>
       <receiver  android:process=":remote" android:name="AlarmReceiver"></receiver>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"/>
</manifest>
```

Comment: if u r getting green android icon bez u have set `android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"` for Appliction in Manifest  .

Comment: android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" instead android:icon="@drawable/another icon"

Comment: @opcOde : or if it's your own icon then place it in all drawable folders ldpi,hdpi,mdpi

Comment: delete the green icon from all your drawables.

Comment: @imrankhan thanks it worked you should place an answer so i can accept it

Comment: @opc0de : it's ok,see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You getting green android icon because you have set `android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"` for Appliction in Manifest.xml. if it's your own icon then place it in all drawable folders `drawable-hdpi`,`drawable-ldpi` and `drawable-mdpi`.

Answer (score 1):

Access this website from Google Chrome: [Android Asset Studio - Launcher Icons](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/icons-launcher.html)

Select you custom icon, play around with the options and tweak to your liking and when you are satisfied with the result, use the "**Download .ZIP**" options and you will have a ZIP file with the icon for all sizes ready to use. Don't bother playing around with the Manifest file. Just copy and paste to replace the 4 drawable folders and you will be all set.

This does take all the guess work away from a simple and yet cumbersome task.