# AndroidManifest.xml Showing Wrong android:icon and android:roundIcon

Tags: icons, android-manifest

[Answer: I do not know if this is the correct thing to do, but it works. So if there is a better answer, please say below. I changed all my normal and round icons in all my different mipmap resolutions folders to `png` files rather than `webp`. Then I copied both round and normal icons to the same name with '_foreground' in it, eg `ic_launcher.png` => `ic_launcher_foreground.png`. So effectively I have 4 icon files in each resolution directory. Then in my AndroidManifest.xml file I changed each line to the foreground icon, ie `android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"` => `android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_foreground"` and `android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"` => `android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round_foreground"`]

The icons shown in my AndroidManifest.xml are the green-android-robot.

In this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9850859/icon-not-showing-android) it says I need to put my icons in the folders drawable-hdpi,drawable-ldpi and drawable-mdpi.

I cannot see where I have these directories.

How do I set them up?

And what do I call my icon files?

(Note, I have the folder mipmap|ic_launcher with all my proper 'webp' icons in there. I thought they were the ones that would be used.)

Should these be png, or are the webp OK?